# Logging Serial port Data

Tags: logging, serial

Unless I'm missing something, there appears to be no simple way in *NIX to read from a serial port directly into a file

I had imagined something as simple as `cat /dev/ttyX > file` but apparently not

Does anyone know a trick that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to capture data from a serial port, Minicom might work. I believe it supports logging to a file.

I thought doing a cat /dev/ttySx would work as well...are you sure it's mapped to the proper serial port? Is something else not allowing the device file to be opened? What happens if you just cat the file instead of redirecting it?

Comment: Maybe it is something to do with line-buffering?

Comment: Strangly, This got sorted by playing with minicom... After HUP and quitting minicom, cat > file works :S Sorry for the time wasted.

Comment: It could be that the port needed settings reset to defaults or was set in a funny mode.